# Build issues with Gradle Android studio 0.2.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've updated my Android Studio Version to 0.2.1 and since then when I open a clean new project and try to build + run it I get the following Error:

> Abnormal build process termination:  Error: Could not find or load
>   main class Files

Do you know how can I avoid it? Am I doing someting wrong?

Comment: Michael, we need more information to troubleshoot this issue. For example, can you attach the stack trace? Does this happen on the command line as well? If you think this is a bug, please file a ticket using this link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug and attach idea.log and build.log files (on Android Studio select the menu "Help" > "Show Log".

Comment: Alex, I have no stuck trace - the project cannot be complied.

Comment: I found an open issue for the same behavior after updating the client version:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=57820

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to bring Android Studio back into working state. I gave up on the 0.2.1 update and reverted to 0.2.0, which we all know worked just fine. Here's how I did it:
I uninstalled Android Studio ( Add/Remove Programs ), deleted the contents of \Android\android-studio ( except for sdk folder and SDK Manger.exe ) and then downloaded and installed the more stable version from the bundle right here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Updating
After that, you should be able to reopen the projects you were working on, without encountering any other errors. Good luck!