# Failed to import Gradle project on android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I know that this has been asked for 10 times but I have tried all solutions have been proposed on stackoverflow but none of them worked for me.
I have tried these but no result:

[Android Studio Stuck at Gradle Download on create new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580873/android-studio-stuck-at-gradle-download-on-create-new-project)

[Android Studio error installing Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585869/android-studio-error-installing-gradle)

[Build issues with Gradle Android studio 0.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745192/build-issues-with-gradle-android-studio-0-2-1)

[image]

Comment: what kind of project are you importing? Ant, Gradle, Idea, Eclipse?

Comment: i'm not importing projects... I'm just trying to create new project.

Comment: I have stumbled upon this before on linux, it was related to environment variables not being set when Android Studio launches.

Comment: @kabuto178
No solution yet. I'm using eclipse for now to do the projects in hand.

Comment: @robotoaster 
I've updated the JDK and set the environment variables properly.

Comment: I'm still baffled by this error, I have tried setting variables again but no luck yet.

Comment: from the screenshot it seems IDE cant open log file in .gradle folder. Delete entire .gradle folder and try again. If no joy check if android studio has read/write permission in there. Alternatively try run Android Studio in administrative, this way you can rule out permission problem.

Comment: @robotoaster I did your suggestion, not working still.

Comment: can you post that log file message is referring to?

Comment: @robotoaster Sorry I didn't have time to make the android studio working. I had a deadline to meet. I deleted it and got back to the old fashion bug free eclipse ;)

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when we work with android sdk studio different from what you should do is install Android Support Repository
https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/knownissues